# Is there any way to export sequence diagram generated by visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sequence-diagram

I am using `Generate Sequence Diagram` feature of Visual Studio.

I have to show my sequence diagram to someone who don't have Visual Studio Ultimate Edition

Is there any way to export the sequence diagram to any format so that it can be viewed outside Visual Studio?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsclassdesigner/thread/6c6f5d78-cc46-4637-a659-83f7ad14be5f

Comment: Yes, I already tried this. Problem is print as XPS prints everything in one page. So nothing is visible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried again with approach mentioned in this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsclassdesigner/thread/6c6f5d78-cc46-4637-a659-83f7ad14be5f) posted by Bolu

I played with the print options and selected the largest available paper size.

It is working for now but I am afraid for large diagrams it might fail

Answer (score 7):

This answer works in VS 2012:

1. Open the sequence diagram
2. select the whole diagram by CTRL+A
3. copy it to the clipboard -> CTRL+C
4. go to an open MS-Word document and hit CTRL+V to paste it

the diagram is pasted and you can perform image editing, printing, etc. there

Answer (score 2):

Haris didn't really explain his answer in any detail, and the link isn't really very clear either, but it seems that the solution is to print-to-XPS-file. This worked for me and the XPS file can be converted to another file format fairly readily.

Answer (score 1):

Printing as PDF works well (using [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp) for example).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit of a 'trick' but you always can make a screenshot (control or alt + PrtScreen), copy it to mspaint and save it as a bitmap/png file.

Comment: Tried that to but page has scroll bars both horizontal and vertical. I will have to combine images :)

Comment: @HarisHasan I copied and pasted an activity diagram directly into Paint.Net with no issues.

Comment: You cannot zoom in? otherwise you can extend the pic in mspaint and paste the second part over (right of) the first one. Might involve some cautious locating the pasting point.